# How to prevent a kable from splitting between pages?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am knitting to pdf using `kable()` to draw some tables. I create a few tables functionally, thus some of them end up being split between pages. Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

I know I could just move to a new page after each table but I would much rather have multiple kables on the same page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're only exporting to PDF, then try this:

```
knitr::kable(
  my_data,
  format    = "latex",
  longtable = FALSE
)
```

A **longtable** table allows page breaks between rows. Looking at the code for `knitr:::kable_latex`, which `kable` calls, the default *should* be `longtable = FALSE`.  But explicitly setting this argument makes sure you're not making longtables.